# Actions to perform after WizardPage is shown

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I'm extending WizardPage class and what I exactly need is to perform some actions after the wizard page is shown. In my case I need to popup a warning dialog after my page is shown. Is there any method like postShowPage or something where I can perform necessary actions after my page is shown?

Comment: Do you mean when Finish is clicked or do you mean when Next/Previous is clicked?

Comment: When NEXT/PREVIOUS is clicked and as soon as my page is shown I need to popup a warning dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `setVisible` method of `WizardPage` to do something when the page becomes visible (or invisible):

```java
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible)
{
  ... your code

  super.setVisible(visible);
}
```